# How to rjust text lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
358.0      11.3       6.9      12.8    0.0069
359.6     273.8     149.8     101.6    0.0069
```

I want above lines to be in following format

```
358.0     11.3      6.9       12.8     0.0069
359.6     273.8     149.8     101.6    0.0069
```

I have tried 'rjust' like in following:

```
with open(infilename) as f:
    next(f)
    for lines in f:
        line = lines.split()
        l = line[0].rjust(25) + line[1].rjust(10) + line[2].rjust(10) + line[3].rjust(10) + line[4].rjust(10) + '\n'
```

'rjust' adds to last value but I want each column to start with reference to extreme left so that all the columns are equally spaced. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to left justify them, not right justify them.

Comment: Thanks. I used `line[0].rjust(25) + line[1].ljust(10)......` and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case , it would be more readable to use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Note unless explicitly specified, default justification is left.

```
print "{:25}{:10}{:10}{:10}{:10}".format(*line)
```